# Como chamar um role "Admin" em um IF no C#?

Tags: c#

Galera eu criei varias roles para que eu faça um controle de acesso. Portanto quero saber como chamar a role do admin para eu passar em um if, tipo exemplo que colocarei abaixo no meu _layout:

```
  @if ("Aqui que eu preciso saber como chamar a role admin")
                {
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Início", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Sobre", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contato", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                }
                else
                {
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Sobre", "About", "Home")</li>
                }
```

Aqui é como eu criei a role em meu arquivo startup:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
        createRolesandUsers();
    }


    // In this method we will create default User roles and Admin user for login  
    private void createRolesandUsers()
    {
        ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();

        var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));
        var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));


        // In Startup iam creating first Admin Role and creating a default Admin User   
        if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Admin"))
        {

            // criando a role do usuario Admin 
            var role = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole();
            role.Name = "Admin";
            roleManager.Create(role);

            //Aqui estou criando o usuario que terá o acesso completo                 

            var user = new ApplicationUser();
            user.UserName = "ebase";
            user.Email = "ebase@teste.com.br";

            string userPWD = "123456";

            var chkUser = UserManager.Create(user, userPWD);

            //Add default User to Role Admin  
            if (chkUser.Succeeded)
            {
                var result1 = UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Admin");

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{

}
```

Comment: Passando o nome Admin não esta funcionando, qual seria a forma correta? O menu continua não sendo exibido depois de logado

Comment: O usuário possui a permissão de admin na tabela de AspNetUserRoles ?
A role de admin está cadastrada com o mesmo nome em AspNetUsers ?

Comment: eu não entendi, eu preciso fazer alguma coisa na base de dados???

Comment: Sim, você deve ter salvo na tabela AspNetRoles, o id da role e o nome, exemplo:
**1  -  Admin** 
E na tabela de AspNetUsersRoles o id do usuário e o id da role, exemplo:
**UserId | RoleId **
**   2       |    1  **

Comment: Verifique também se o usuário está logado

Comment: O ID de ambas as tabelas devem ser iguais então???

Comment: Sim, porque a coluna RoleId é chave estrangeira. E o id da mesma deve existir em AspNetRoles

Comment: Eu criei aqui um novo usuário portanto quando fui na tabela AspNetUserRoles tava tudo null, apenas estão salvo os dados na tabela AspNetUsers e AspNetRoles, como faço para salvar isso na outra tabela? Desculpe mais é que to começando agora com C#, antes eu programava em PHP

Comment: Cara consegui, fiz o que vc falou, fui no AspNetUserRoles e coloquei o ID e o roleid iguais dos demais, dai deu certo